# dynamically change the window.location + ID jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pull the URL from the link and assign it to the window.location and it's not working. I know I'm close, what am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mypage").attr("href", $("#redirectme").attr("href") );
    window.location + "#redirectme";
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="mypage">My link</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to the `href` of the `redirectme` element or browse to the `#redirectme` hash? Your example is confusing.

Comment: your example is setting the href of your #mypage link, not pulling it.

Comment: I want the page to redirect me to google, by updating window.location with ID mypage

Comment: You want google.com or google.com/#redirectme?

Comment: google.com, i thought by using + that would take me there

Comment: @Evan Paulpro has your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use assignment (`=`) instead of addition (`+`):

```
window.location = $("#mypage").prop("href");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CtK2h/2/) (Waits 5 seconds, so you can see it, and then redirects)

Comment: Thanks @Zenith. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    window.location = ("#mypage").attr("href") + "#redirectme";
});

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="mypage">My link</a>
```